# No wireless connection at all

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet-connection

I downloaded 12.04 and i'm new with Linux. I can't connect to the internet and my WiFi doesn't even show up, in fact no wireless connections show up. It won't even give me the option to connect to the internet. I'm on my HP mini laptop... Please help

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Dash, and looking for additional Drivers, if it is available, then just pluged from cable then click active, then unplug, and reboot, let me know if it work.